# Changing acceleration rate gives BAD_REQUEST on Movesense for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, movesense

I would like to change the acceleration rate on my Movesense device via `Xamarin API`.

I already tried the following, but it just gives me a `BAD_REQUEST`:

```cs
string NEW_ACC_CONFIG = "{\"config\":2}";
var op = await Plugin.Movesense.CrossMovesense.Current.ApiCallAsync<string>(
    Name,
    Plugin.Movesense.Api.MdsOp.PUT,
    "/Meas/Acc/Config/",
    NEW_ACC_CONFIG
);
```

It seems that the contract which is sent is empty.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

BAD_REQUEST means that the NEW_ACC_CONFIG you are giving is not in a correct format or that the values are incorrect. Comparing it to the [acc.yaml](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/meas/acc.yaml) shows that the parameter *config* is not an integer (2) but an object of format *AccConfig* i.e. the following JSON should work:

```
{
    "config":
    {
        "GRange":2
    }
}
```

*Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*